# How to use a variables quartile and inter-quartile range in and If statment?

Tags: sas

I'm doing some data cleaning in SAS, which I am very new to using, and I'm trying to create a new variable where I set values outside my cap and floor to the value of the cap and floor. I decided my floor by Q1-1.5*IQR and cap by Q3+1.5*IQR. Using an if statement to make the new variable I have the code below. I don't know how to include the values of my cap and floor outside of just calculating them by hand but i feel as though there should be a better way to do that. How do i use the use the quartile values and IQR in my code?

```
data practice.ipo_refined2;
    set practice.ipo;
    if 'Price.Revision'n > Q3 + qrange*1.5 then 'Price.Revision.Windsor'n = Q3+qrange*1.5;
    else if 'Price.Revision'n < Q1-qrange*1.5 then 'Price.Revision.Windsor'n = Q1-qrange*1.5;
    else 'Price.Revision.Windsor'n = 'Price.Revision'n;
    keep 'Initial.Return'n 'Price.Revision'n 'High.Tech'n 'Price.Revision.Windsor'n;
run;
```

Comment: Where are the variables Q1 Q3 QRANGE?  Show example data using CARDS and a data step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this example will be helpful.

```
proc summary data=sashelp.class;
   var height;
   output out=q q1=q1 q3=q3 qrange=qrange;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data class;
   set sashelp.class;
   if _n_ eq 1 then set q;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]